# Participial Phrase as Verb Modifier?

Tags: modifiers, participles

On the internet, I only read about participial phrases acting as noun modifiers.
But when I read various newspaper articles, it seems that participial phrases are also used as verb modifiers, or even as clause modifiers.

- Suggested example for verb modifier: *He came to town, driving in his new car.*
- Suggested example for clause modifier: *EQZCO posted a quarter loss of $10 million dollars, causing its stocks to decrease by $5 per share.*

Can that be?

Comment: It will be better if you post an example or two of what you have come across.

Comment: Example for verb modifier: 
He came to town, driving in his new car.

Comment: Example for clause modifier:
X company posted a quarter loss of $10 million dollars, causing its stocks to decrease by $5 per share.

Comment: I'd say that "driving his new car" and "causing its stocks to decrease by $5 per share" are adjuncts in clause structure, i.e. they modify the verb phrase.

Comment: @LeeMee322: I would like to change the order a little to highlight the linkage of participial phrase to the subject (noun). a) Driving his new car, he came to town. Who drove the car? Who came to the town? He.  b) Causing its stocks to decrease by $5 per share, X company posted a quarter loss of $10 million dollars. Here also, both actions are done by X company.

Comment: @Ram Pillai: Thanks a lot! So, is it wrong that participial phrases can be used as verb modifiers?

Comment: Participial phrase and other clause(s) in a sentence have a common subject. At the same time, that single subject is linked to the verbal connotations in both phrase and the clause. That is the linkage. In the sentence "Driving his new car, he came to town", the common subject 'he' talks about driving and coming to the town too.

Comment: @Ram Pillai 'Participial phrase and other clause(s) in a sentence have a common subject. ' I suppose you mean 'agent/cause'; participles are non-finite. But in 'Saturday's $3.5 million jackpot was won, sending the estimated top prize for Wednesday to $1 million.' what is the common agent/cause? There _must_ be an involvement of the winning of the jackpot and not just the Saturday jackpot itself in the causal factor of the in-/decrease in the Wednesday jackpot.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, the example I used in my comments are, Driving his new car, he came to town. In your example also, there should be a subject; it is just that it is hidden. I can relate what you say that a non-finite verb doesn't refer to a time/ tense. The sentence "Driving his new car, he came to town." is a single-clause sentence, and naturally the tense/ time impacts the main clause and the phrase (here participle phrase.)

Comment: Are you sure you understand the difference between the terms 'agent' and 'subject'? If you actually _do_, and are using 'subject' to stand for 'notional / semantic subject' as some grammars do (eg in imperative sentences), it violates Gricean maxims to do so without making this very clear. //// But the sentence I gave **does have** an indisputable subject, 'Saturday's $3.5 million jackpot'. In the simple passive sentence 'Jack was hit by Jill', the word 'Jack' is the subject (though the agent is the actual naughty girl Jill).